# reading writing a varbinary

Tags: sql, file, dataset, varbinary

i'm trying to do this :

```
string path = C:/blablabla/file.png
byte[] byteFile = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteFile, 0, byteFile.Length);
string SQL = @"INSERT INTO UserIcon (image) VALUES('" + s + "')";
```

i want to put the file in a sql varbinary(max)
the request looks like ok, but i'm not sure

To get back the file i'm trying to do this :

```
string SQL2 = @"SELECT image FROM UserIcon WHERE id =xx";
DataSet mydataset = connect.ExecuteSelectQuery(SQL2);
DataTable myDataTable = mydataset.Tables[0];
```

connect is a custom connector to the database that puts data read in a DataSet
i can ONLY give him a string

Then i'm quite lost, i can't get the file back.
i tried things like that :

```
foreach (DataRow dr in myDataTable.Rows)
{
// doesn't work
(string)dr["image"]; 
//give me a corrupted file
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\test\file.png", (byte[])dr["Image"]); 
}
```

What do you think i should do to make that work?

No need to tell me " don't put big images in a database", my boss told me to do that and we already tried and it's not my decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the file back, because you broke it.

The `GetString` method is used to convert data *back* from binary to a string after converting it from a string to binary in the first place. If you do that on any arbitrary data, any values that doesn't map to a character will be replaced with a question mark.

To store the binary value you would use a parameterised query. Example:

```
string sql = "insert into UserIcon (image) values (@Image)";
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection) {
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", byteFile);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Once you have stored the data correctly, you can read it and get the data back using `(byte[])dr["Image"]`.

#### Edit:

To make a binary work in a string, you need to format it as a binary literal:

```
string bin = "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(byteFile).Replace("-", String.Empty);
string SQL = "insert into UserIcon (image) values (" + bin + ")";
```

Comment: I would like to do like that, but because the connector is custom made and i have to use it, i can't use parameters.
I can only give the database a string.

Comment: @Adrien: Then you need to format the data as a binary literal. I added code for that above.

Comment: That looks like a good idea. But here's the problem now :
i write 4516 bytes but i read a 9034 bytes. ( so twice + 2 )
i gues the 2 comes from 0x
though i think it's almost work, isn't the string converted i wonder?

Comment: @Adrien: Then the binary literal is interpreted as a string. Have you added any apostrophes in the code? Is the field actually `varbinary` and not `varchar`?

Comment: It works now,
apostrophes there was :-)
Thanks a lot for your help to fix that!

Comment: For info it was a varbinary field

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code i used, feel free to use it. It works for sql DB.
I don't know yet if it works for oracle database.

```
private void AddImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //select files to add, in my case images
        FileDialog Filedlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (filedlgdefaultpath.Equals("") | filedlgdefaultpath == null)
        {
            Filedlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        }
        else
        {   
        Filedlg.InitialDirectory = @"filedlgdefaultpath";
    }
    if (!Filedlg.CheckPathExists) Filedlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";

    Filedlg.Filter = "Image Files|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png";
    Filedlg.FilterIndex = 1;
    Filedlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    //if files are selected add them in the database
    if (Filedlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        filedlgdefaultpath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Filedlg.FileName);
        string[] imagepaths = Filedlg.FileNames;
        connect.OpenConnection();
        foreach (string path in imagepaths)
        {
            writeFileToDB(connect, path);
        }
        connect.CloseConnection();
    }
    else return;

}
private void writeFileToDB( DBConnector connect, string path)
{
    byte[] byteFile = File.ReadAllBytes(path); 
    string bin = "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(byteFile).Replace("-", String.Empty);
    string SQL = @"INSERT INTO UserIcon (image) VALUES(" + bin + ")";
    connect.ExecuteNonSelectQuery(SQL);
}
```

Comment: From what I can see Oracle uses the same syntax for binary literals, so that should work.

Comment: Hm... that contradicts the documentation that I found before, but it's hard to know what you found when you are looking for documentation for Oracle... However, I found a blog post outlining the different binary literal formats, for Oracle it seems that you should omit the `"0x"` string from the `bin` value, and use `VALUES(hextoraw('" + bin + "'))` in the query.

Comment: this one gives a ORA-01704: string literal too long
I think it's not possible in oracle in a single line.
a solution here looks like possible through multiple update :
https://community.oracle.com/thread/1068414